# Problema con apilado de DIVS y posición absolute

Tags: css

Tengo un problema que está causando muchísimos quebraderos de cabeza. Tengo que decir que soy autodidacta y que a pesar de que llevo mas de 5 años diseñando páginas web y aprendiendo sobre la marcha nunca me había encontrado este problema.

La idea es colocar un `div` con posición `absolute` por encima de su padre y los padres de este usando el valor de `z-index`. Lo he hecho otras veces y no hay problema, simplemente se le dan unos valores a `top` y `left` para hacer que el `div` en cuestión se desplace por encima del padre. Pues bien, en este caso no funciona, se queda oculto dentro del padre como en la siguiente imagen.

[image: position absolute nor working]

Tengo entendido que este problema estaba causado por no posicionar los `div` padre, pero he probado de todas las maneras posibles. Necesito que alguien con mas conocimientos me diga donde está el fallo. Aquí dejo el código:

```css
.mainwidth{
 max-width: 1439px;
 margin: auto;
}
#main-myprofile{
 overflow: auto;
 margin-top: 100px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 4999;!important
}
#cuadro-panel{
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 border-radius: 2px;
 z-index: 5000;!important
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
#menu-user-panel{
 float: left;
 background-color: #EFEFFF;
 width: 19%;
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
 z-index: 5001;!important
}
#load-options-panel{
 float: right;
 background-color: #EFEFFF;
 width: 80%;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 display: block;
 z-index: 5002;!important
}
#cabecera-panel{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #EFEFFF;
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #B9B9FF;
 overflow: auto;
 height: 80px;
 z-index: 5003;!important
}
#pic-usuario-panel{
 width: 20%;
 height: 80px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 5004;!important
}
#preview-user-panel{
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 border: 6px solid #B9B9FF;
 top: -40%;
 left: 25%;
 z-index: 9999;!important
}
```

```html
<div class="mainwidth" id="main-myprofile">
 <div id="cuadro-panel">
     <div id="cabecera-panel">
         <div id="pic-usuario-panel">
             <img src="<?=$rowUser["foto"]?>" alt="" id="preview-user-panel">
            </div>
        </div>
     <div id="menu-user-panel">
        a
        </div>
        <div id="load-options-panel">
        b<br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comenté algunas lineas de tu `CSS` para lograr el efecto que quieres y eliminé `!important` ya que lo tenías declarado después del punto y coma (*debe ser antes de cerrar con punto y coma*).

Comenté la propiedad `overflow` ya que es la que se encarga de recortar tu contenido al sobrepasar las dimensiones del contenedor... De acuerdo a la [definición de w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) :

> La propiedad overflow especifica qué debería suceder si el contenido desborda el cuadro de un elemento.
>
> Esta propiedad especifica si se debe recortar el contenido o agregar barras de desplazamiento cuando el contenido de un elemento es demasiado grande para caber en un área específica.

```css
.mainwidth{
 max-width: 1439px;
 margin: auto;
}
#main-myprofile{
 /*overflow: auto;*/
 margin-top: 100px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 4999;
}
#cuadro-panel{
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
 border-radius: 2px;
 z-index: 5000;!important
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
}
#menu-user-panel{
 float: left;
 background-color: #EFEFFF;
 width: 19%;
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
 z-index: 5001;
}
#load-options-panel{
 float: right;
 background-color: #EFEFFF;
 width: 80%;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 display: block;
 z-index: 5002;
}
#cabecera-panel{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #EFEFFF;
 /*position: relative;*/
 border-bottom: 4px solid #B9B9FF;
 overflow: auto;
 height: 80px;
 z-index: 5003;
}
#pic-usuario-panel{
 width: 20%;
 height: 80px;
 /*overflow: hidden;*/
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5004;
}
#preview-user-panel{
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 border: 6px solid #B9B9FF;
 top: -40%;
 left: 25%;
 z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainwidth" id="main-myprofile">
   <div id="cuadro-panel">
      <div id="cabecera-panel">
          <div id="pic-usuario-panel">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" id="preview-user-panel">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="menu-user-panel">
        a
      </div>
      <div id="load-options-panel">
        b<br><br><br><br><br><br>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sublime! Simplemente estaba en la combinación de los overflow correcta! Gracias gracias gracias!